# Docker image created by quarkus-container-image-docker getting an issue of CrashLoopBackOff in k8s deployment, whereas with quarkus-jib working fine

Tags: quarkus

Currently, I'm facing an issue(CrashLoopBackOff) with the image generated by quarkus-container-image-docker. Whereas if i use, quarkus-container-image-jib, with this extension am not facing this type of issue.

FYI, Kubernetes Manifest files are same in both the cases

Comment: What does the pod log contain before crashing?